# Update location on google maps

Tags: java, android, multithreading, google-maps

I'm wondering what the best/suggested way to update my location on the map is. I'm trying to update my location once it changes and draw a line on the map for the route I've walked. I was thinking of using a thread who calls for my location method once every 5 sec (?) but I doubt this would be a recomended way to do this.

question: Best way to update my location on the map and how do I draw a route for the path I've taken.

If anyone could point me to the right direction I would highly appreciate that.

Comment: Use `OnLocationChanged` listener for that.

Comment: use combination of thread with OnLocationChanged listener

Comment: I thought this method was depricated?  [https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/quentin7b/android-location-tracker) library. It's very useful and customize-able. You can set how frequently you want to get location. Just keep the reference of previous location. Define global instance of `LocationTracker` and then set it up like this.

```
private void setupLocationTracker() {
    TrackerSettings settings = new TrackerSettings()
            .setUseGPS(true)
            .setUseNetwork(true)
            .setUsePassive(true)
            .setTimeBetweenUpdates(1000 * 5)    //You can set it according to your needs
            .setMetersBetweenUpdates(10);    //Or you can set this too.
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationTracker = new LocationTracker(this, settings) {
        @Override
        public void onLocationFound(@NonNull Location location) {
            LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            //if(latLngList.size() == 0) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Current Location"));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation, 15.0f), 3000, null);
            //Write your function to draw line
            drawLine(previousLocation, currentLocation);
            previousLocation = currentLocation;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimeout() {
            Log.d("MESSAGE", "Time out");
        }
    };
}
```

And then call `locationTraker.startListening()` and `locationTracker.stopListening()` whenever and wherever you want to. Just don't forget to call `stopListening()` inside `onPause()`.